# run gulp via jQuery

Tags: jquery, gulp

Did anyone ever run gulp from any javascript (like jquery)? I got an web based interface to configure some template settings in a project, so a user of this interface needs to publish this settings (written in a .scss file).
Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I didn't try anything so far since I'm still searching for a solution. I can't find anything across Google to approach.

Comment: If you want to run scripts like gulp, you'll need a server to interact with that server's shell and perform the gulp tasks, which can then be return to your front-end

Comment: Yes, I know :) but my idea was: not do an ajax request and trigger a php exec() - i thought it should be possible to do this also via javascript (like some kind of js console).

Comment: I guess you could run gulp with browserSync and expose it to the outside world. You can then make browserSync run gulp tasks with the middleware parameter. A better option to run JavaScript on the server side would be a nodeJS server.